# "The results demonstrate" vs. "The results have demonstrated" or "The results demonstrated"

Tags: tense, formal-language

From an analytical method validation report, a sentence coming just after a table that contains the final results of a method parameter investigation:

> 1. The results **demonstrate** reliable detection of residual host cell proteins at the specified level and their reliable quantification in solutions with concentrations of 6.25 ng/ml and higher.

Is it okay to use the present simple here, or would it be better to use the present perfect or past simple?

> 2. The results **have demonstrated** reliable detection of residual host cell proteins at the specified level and their reliable quantification in solutions with concentrations of 6.25 ng/ml and higher.
> 3. The results **demonstrated** reliable detection of residual host cell proteins at the specified level and their reliable quantification in solutions with concentrations of 6.25 ng/ml and higher.

I tend to use the present simple in such sentences, but a fellow translator said she sometimes uses the present perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, most writers would use the present tense:

> The results **demonstrate**...

There are, of course, specific circumstances which might call for a perfect form, as, for instance, when contrasting current with previous findings.